# How can I implement throttling by the message value using MassTransit? (backend is SNS/SQS but flexible)

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I'm interested in using MassTransit as the event bus to help me bust a cache, but I'm not sure how to properly throttle the service.

#### The situation

I have a .Net service that has a `refreshCache(itemId)` API which recomputes the cache for `itemId`. I want to call this whenever code in my organization modifies any data related to `itemId`.

However, due to legacy code, I may have 10 events for a given itemId emitted within the same second. Since the `refreshCache(itemId)` call is expensive, I'd prefer to only call it once every second or so *per itemId*.

For instance, imagine that I have 10 events emitted for `item1` and then 1 event emitted for `item2`. I'd like `refreshCache` to be called twice, once with `item1` and once with `item2`.

#### Trouble with MassTransit

I could send event messages that essentially are just `itemId` over SNS/SQS, and the .Net service could use a MassTransit consumer to listen to that SQS queue and call `refreshCache` for each message. Ideally, I can also throttle either in SNS/SQS or MassTransit.

I've read these docs: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/rate-limiter.html and have tried to find the middleware in the code but wasn't able to locate it.

They seem to suggest that the rate-limiting just delays the delivery of messages, which means that my `refreshCache` would get called 10 times with `item1` before getting called with `item2`. Instead, I'd prefer it get called once per item, ideally both immediately.

Similarly, it seems as if SNS and SQS can either [rate-limit in-order delivery](https://www.jeremydaly.com/how-to-use-sns-and-sqs-to-distribute-and-throttle-events/) or [throttle based on the *queue*](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/89mj53/rate_limiting_an_sqs_queue/) but not based on the contents of that queue. It would not be feasible for me to have separate queues per `itemId`, as there will be 100,000+ distinct itemIds.

#### The Ask

Is what I'm trying to do possible in MassTransit? If not, is it possible via SQS? I'm also able to be creative with using RabbitMQ or adding in Lambdas, but would prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: Is this a shared, distributed cache, or a per-node cache – or is it an edge cache in something like Redis that is used by an edge service (such as a query API, etc.)?

Comment: This is a per-node cache - we may have a separate queue per-host, or use the same SQS queue for all hosts but have the host be a part of the key

Comment: So does each node need to update its cache for every item1 batch, I don't see how you could use a single queue since each node would process separately to update their cache.

Comment: Ah - so each node would have a separate SQS queue, that's correct. 

In any case, you'd still see multiple updates for item1 coming into the queue in a given second (assume only node1 cares about item1). So, we'd still need to throttle SQS / node1 such that we call refreshCache(item1) once for all of those multiple item1 events coming in during that second.